# Docker build npm install error network timeout

Tags: node.js, docker

I'm try build image to node app, but when i execute docker build showed an error left run npm install

**npm ERR! network timeout at: https://registry.npmjs.org/cookie/-/cookie-0.4.0.tgz**

follow docker file content:

```
FROM node:13

# Create app directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Install app dependencies
# A wildcard is used to ensure both package.json AND package-lock.json are copied
# where available (npm@5+)
COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install
# If you are building your code for production
# RUN npm ci --only=production

# Bundle app source
COPY . .

EXPOSE 8080
CMD [ "node", "server.js" ]
```

follow my package.json

```
{
  "name": "backend",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "private": true,
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "Bruno Cassiamani",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "config": "^3.3.1",
    "consign": "^0.1.6",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "request": "^2.88.2",
    "xml2js": "^0.4.23"
  }
}
```

OS relase:      CentOS Linux release 8.1.1911 (Core)

Docker release: Docker version 19.03.8, build afacb8b

print error:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q2l2B.png

Answer (score 30, accepted):

[RESOLVED] the problem was in network of docker, then i executed the folow command:

```
docker build -t cassiamani/nodeapp --network=host .
```

--network=host use dns from host, for me it's worked.

reference: https://www.linode.com/community/questions/19710/docker-npm-timeout-on-linode

Comment: searching deeper i discover the real problem, in the Centos release 8 has a problem with dns on firewall, solution reference: https://github.com/docker/for-linux/issues/957

Answer (score 4):

In my case working solution was to clean up docker image cache with

```
docker image prune
```

And make sure that you can wget needed npm package inside required docker image. For example I used node:lts-alpine. So, you have to run

```
docker run -it node:lts-alpine sh
```

And run (it was some dependent "yorkie" package) in order to make sure that it can resolve network address and download the file.

```
wget https://registry.npmjs.org/yorkie/-/yorkie-2.0.0.tgz
```

Answer (score 4):

I know this comes late, but it might help someone, the below solution works for me.

1. Create /etc/docker/daemon.json
2. Put below code into it

```json
{
  "dns": ["1.1.1.1", "8.8.8.8"]
}
```

3. Finally, run **systemctl daemon-reload** and **systemctl restart docker.service**

Comment: Thanks @Ahmard, you saved me from wasting more of my precious time!