# --network=host works in docker build but not in docker-compose

Tags: node.js, docker, ubuntu, docker-compose

I have a node.js application and in Ubuntu once it runs `npm install` it is giving timeout error like below.

[Docker build npm install error network timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61760047/docker-build-npm-install-error-network-timeout)

Solution is adding `--network=host`

```
docker build -t cassiamani/nodeapp --network=host .
```

But I have a `docker-compose.yaml` file like below;

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  nodejs-server:    
    network_mode: "host"
    build:
      context: ./api
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    container_name: node-api
    volumes:
       - ./api:/usr/src/app/api
       - /usr/src/app/api/node_modules
  react-ui:
    network_mode: "host"
    build:
      context: ./web/web-app
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    container_name: react-ui
    stdin_open: true
    volumes:
       - ./web/web-app:/usr/src/app/my-app
       - /usr/src/app/my-app/node_modules
```

And it still stucks on `npm install` command, and adding `network_mode: "host"` did not work. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Did you run `docker-compose restart` instead of `docker-compose up`?

Comment: How are you actually using Docker in this setup?  If you need to routinely disable Docker networking, and your source code is injected from the host system, would your setup be any different using plain Node without Docker?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you've done it specifies the network settings at run-time. To specify them at build time, you need to have `network:` under the `build:` section, like this

```
build:
  context: ./api
  network: host
```